# Manipulating a Form's data in Google Sheets

Tags: javascript, google-sheets

I'm using Google Drive/Sheets to host my personal film ratings list, and I thought it'd be a lot easier than this.

I've set up a form which asks about the film and what rating I give it (out of 4 categories), and then it puts this into a sheet. The data is inputting fine, but I want the sheet to automatically find out the average of my 4 individual ratings, and then add an overall rating to that row of data.

What I can work out...

[image: What I have]

What I would like...

[image: What I want]

I'm assuming it requires some kind of trigger from the form submission which then performs some javascript and inputs a new piece of data in the appropriate column and row, but I just want work it out. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Navigate in top menu to Tools->Script editor in Summary spreadsheet

Place this code inside

```
function setAvarage() {
  var summaryCloumn = 10 //row J 
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
  sheet.getRange(lastRow, summaryCloumn).setFormula("SUM(E"+lastRow+":H"+lastRow+")/4");
};
```

Now setup the trigger in very same script editor Materials->Triggers (first option - unfortunately I do not have docs in english so name can be slightly different..)
Choose add trigger
"setAvarage", "From table", "on change"

just tested and worked...